# How do I use a variable from one method oin another?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to define an array with the 26 letters from the alphabet. Then I want to use the Array in another method. How can I use the `arrayEins` variable in the `shiftLeft` function? Thanks in advance!

```java
public class VigenereCipher {
    public static void[] dasAlphabet() {
        // char[] arrayEins = new char[26];
        char[] arrayEins;
        for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
            arrayEins = new char[]{(char) i};
        }
    }

    public static void shiftLeft() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dasAlphabet();
        shiftLeft();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `arrayEins` in a scope which makes it visible in the body of a static method. Making it a private static field of `VigenereCipher` would do. You have another problem: can you please explain exactly what you think the line `arrayEins = new char[]{(char) I};` does?

Comment: Hey, I want to declare the arrayEins as all the letters from the alphabet, which start from (char) 97-122, so I thought that I could use that line to declare the numbers as (char), but now I know that that just puts out a new array with length 1. How can i declare my Array all the letters from the alphabet?

Answer (score 0):

The array at `arrayEins` is local to `dasAlphabet`, which means it literally does not exist except when `dasAlphabet` is executing.

You need to declare the array as a static member variable of the class.

But note also this code is wrong:

```
        arrayEins = new char[]{(char) i};
```

This creates a new array each time round the loop, so the final result is an array of length 1, whose sole element has the value 122.